# Arangodb custom filter/visitor for my tree graph

Tags: graph, tree-traversal, arangodb

I have a graph with two edge definitions like this:

```
isDepartment: [organisation] -> [organisation]
hasAccess: [user] -> [organisation]
```

Organisations are nested in a tree (no cycles). There are multiple top-level organisations without any incoming `isDepartment` edges.

Users are granted access to one or more organisations. These can be top-level organisations or organisations somewhere lower down the tree. If a user has access to an organisation, it has access to all child organisations.

I am trying to build a custom visitor or filter that gives me all accessible organisations for a user, including it's path to the root, along with a property if they are accessible or not.

Example, take the following organisation structure:

- Root A

  - Dept. A.1
  - Dept. A.2
- Root B

  - Dept. B.1
  - Dept. B.2
  - Subdept. B.2.1
- Root C

  - Dept. C.1
  - Dept. C.2

Now take a user that hasAccess to `Root A` and `Dept. B.2`. I would like to generate the following result tree:

- Root A, accessible: true

  - Dept. A.1, accessible: true
  - Dept. A.2, accessible: true
- Root B, accessible: false

  - Dept. B.2, accessible: true
  - Subdept. B.2.1, accessible: true

Note that `Root C` and `Dept. B1` are not in the result because they are not accessible to the user, nor are any of their children accessible.

Also note that `Root B` is included but marked as `not accessible`. This is because teh user is granted access to only a child of `Root B` but not the root itself.

How can I write a custom function/visitor/filter that accomplished this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was indeed a challenging question, thank you very much ;)

You can solve this by adding user-defined functions to AQL and use them in the TRAVERSER.

First of all I have registered two AQL visitor functions through arangosh:

```
var aqlfunctions = require("org/arangodb/aql/functions");
aqlfunctions.register("myvisitor::indirectAccess", "function (config, result, vertex) { if(result.length === 0) {result.push({});} result[0][vertex._key] = {hasAccess: true};}")
aqlfunctions.register("myvisitor::noAccess", "function (config, result, vertex) { if (result.length === 0) {result.push({});} result[0][vertex._key] = {hasAccess: false};}")
```

These functions simply do the following:

- `myvisitor::indirectAccess` will be used to traverse down the tree. As in AQL the result is always an Array, we simply at a first document to it (if necessary) to store all the data. Then we assign to the vertexes `_key` property the value `{hasAccess: true}`.
- `myvisitor::noAccess` will be used to traverse up the tree und will store '{hasAccess: false}` in the same way.

Now we can execute the following query which makes use of these visitors:

```
FOR x IN GRAPH_NEIGHBORS(@graph, @userId, {direction: 'outbound'})
LET upwards = TRAVERSAL(organisation, isDepartment, x, 'inbound', {visitor: 'myvisitor::noAccess'})[0]
LET downwards = TRAVERSAL(organisation, isDepartment, x, 'outbound', {visitor: 'myvisitor::indirectAccess'})[0]
RETURN MERGE(upwards, downwards)
```

Short explaination:

1. Find the organizations this user has direct access to.
2. Go up the tree `upwards` and mark everything as "noAccess".
3. Go down the tree `downwards` and mark everything as "access".
4. Merge `upwards` and `downwards`.

If you would like to modify the result format you have to change the registered visitor functions.

Comment: Ohh, this is looking very good. Thank you, I'm going to try it out :-)

Comment: It's not quite right, but I am getting there. I need to add some sorting and nesting (or indenting on vertex.name) in order to get the result I need.